# Probability calculation in python

Tags: python, probability

My problem is: I have 12 players, with 3 of them being named A, B and C, respectively. 12 players are being divided into 2 groups, 6 people each. I need to calculate the probability of player A and B being in the same team, and player C being in thе eopposite one. Math is not my strongsuit, because im pretty sure this is not a hard thing to calculate, but i would be really grateful if you could help me with this one. Here is what i wrote so far:

```
import random

playersnumb = 12
players = list(range(12))

A = random.choice([x for x in range(12)])

B = random.choice([x for x in range(12) if x != A])

C = random.choice([x for x in range(12) if (x != A) and (x != B)])

random.shuffle(players)
team1 = (players[:6])
team2 = (players[6:])

if A in team1:
    print("Player A is in team 1")
else:
    print("Player A is in team 2")
if B in team1:
    print("Player B is in team 1")
else:
    print("Player B is in team 2")
if C in team1:
    print("Player C is in team 1")
else:
    print("Player C is in team 2")
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is a question for mathoverfow: https://mathoverflow.net/
You are asking for help with math, not with your code.

Comment: @kate-melnykova im asking how to solve the problem using code, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a little bit based on your code. The idea is to loop multiple times over your test code, it is not 100% accurate, but i think good enough for you:

```
import random


def calculate(playercount: int = 12) -> bool:
    players = list(range(playercount))

    player_a = random.choice([x for x in range(playercount)])

    player_b = random.choice([x for x in range(playercount) if x != player_a])

    player_c = random.choice([x for x in range(playercount) if (x != player_a) and (x != player_b)])

    random.shuffle(players)
    team1 = (players[:playercount//2])
    team2 = (players[playercount//2:])

    # That are your "positive" events
    return (player_a in team1 and player_b in team1 and player_c in team2) or\
           (player_a in team2 and player_b in team2 and player_c in team1)


def calculate_all(runtimes: int = 100000) -> float:
    counter = 0
    # count all poyitive events
    for i in range(runtimes):
        if calculate():
            counter += 1

    # return how often they appeared, based on all tests
    return counter / runtimes


print("The probability is about {} %".format(calculate_all() * 100))
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways to fill 1 list of six total = 12!/(6! * 6!) `comb(12,6)`

The number of ways to fill a list of six (including A and B and not C) = 9!/(4! * 5!) `comb(9, 4)`

Also, want to find (not A and not B and C) = 9!/(5! * 4!)  `comb(9, 5)`

```
>>> from math import comb
>>> comb(12, 6)
924
>>> comb(9, 4) + comb(9, 5)
252
>>> 252 / 924
0.2727272727272727
```

Comment: I think you need to double that.

Comment: @Heap Overflow I edited my post with a proof of my results. It seems all is well and there is no problem. (or so I think)

Comment: [Try this](https://repl.it/repls/MintyUnknownServices#main.py).

Comment: @Heap Overflow I tried that and if I run it with the 1 line `mean('A' in team1 and 'B' in team1 and 'C' not in team1` and not the following line, the results agree with my results. I think we are not in agreement on what the problem is to be solved.

Comment: @Heap Overflow The problem as I understand it is: **A and B and not C**. I thought that's  what my approach solved.

Comment: A and B just need to be in the same team. But that could be team 1 or it could be team 2. You just removed the latter from my code. That's not right.

Comment: @Heap Overflow Ok I see the distinction you make. I'll see if I change my solution!

Comment: Mathematically I'd btw prefer to just take one player's perspective, i.e., use them as reference.  For example, for player A, there are 11C5 possible teammate combinations. They want B on their team, leaving 4 spots. They don't want C, leaving 9 players for those 4 spots. So A is happy in 9C4 cases out of the 11C5 cases.

Comment: @Heap Overflow Nice method. I would have never considered it.